# Apache Spark: disable dynamic allocation for a single job in an Spark application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark application that launches multiple Spark jobs (here a Spark job means an action on a data-frame such as writing it to HDFS which will launch a DAG of Stages and tasks). I would like to selectively enable dynamic allocation for some of these jobs and disable it for others.

So my question is, is it possible to selectively enable or disable dynamic allocation per a single spark job in an application?. I tried disabling the dynamic allocation in single spark job by using the `option` method in the DataFrameWriter class as shown below.

```
df
 .write
 .option("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
 .parquet("hdfs://target-path")
```

but it didn't work out and by looking at the codebase of Spark it doesn't seem like it is supposed to work like that. The only other option seems like we will have to teardown the current sparkSession and recreate a new one whenever we wanted to switch the dynamic allocation property in my application. Is that the only way or is there is a better alternative to enable and disable dynamic allocation.

Comment: if session is created per job then it can be done per job level.